# Fredholm Integral Equation for Bessel Function

Tags: definite-integrals, bessel-functions

Show (or at least verify) that the solution to the integral equation
$$u(x)=\frac{2}{\pi }  \int_0^{\infty } \frac{\sin
   (x+y) u(y)}{x+y} \, dy$$
is given by $u(x)=J_0(x)$

Answer (score 0):

We will show how to convert the integral equation into a convolution type and solve it by Fourier transforms.

First note that $\int_{-\infty }^0 \frac{\sin
   (x+t) J_0(t)}{x+t} \,
   dt=\int_0^{\infty }
   \frac{\sin (x+t)
   J_0(t)}{x+t} \, dt$. Thus the original problem is equivalent to showing that
$$J_0(x)=\frac{1}{\pi } \int_{-\infty }^{\infty }
   \frac{\sin (x+t)
   J_0(t)}{x+t} \, dt$$
Since $J_0(-x)=J_0(x),$ the above equation is equivalent to
$$J_0(x)=\frac{1}{\pi }  \int_{-\infty }^{\infty }
   \frac{\sin (x-t)
   J_0(t)}{x-t} \, dt$$
The result follows after taking the Fourier transform of both sides and recalling the result for the Fourier transform of a convolution.

Note:$\mathscr{F}\{J_0(x\}=\frac{\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }}
   (\theta (k+1)-\theta
   (k-1))}{\sqrt{1-k^2}}$ and $\mathscr{F}\left\{\frac{\sin
   (x)}{x}\right\}=\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} \theta
   (1-| k| )$

where $\theta (k)=
\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & k<0 \\
 1 & k>0 \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}$